# Lightning LockerService & History.pushState

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

Since implementing `LockerService`, the `History` object ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)) is no longer available.

That's too bad, because I'm using `History.pushState` and `onPopState` events to manage navigation inside my `Lightning Application`.

Is there some workaround to access history object from an org with `LockerService` activated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix to expose SecureWindow.history will be deployed next Tuesday in the next available Summer'16 patch.

Comment: Can you elaborate on SecureWindow.history?